# File open problem with many process in C

Tags: c++, windows, file, process, mutual-exclusion

Iam working in c++ .i have an problem while run an application ,which have my dll within it ,My dll code is suitable to application (needed process).i wrote a log file (xml file) throughout  application  using fopen within all function(dll source) ,here i receive exception like "cannot access the file ,due to using by another process." .please help me ,how can manage a file ,where can use only one process at a time...

Comment: Are you constantly using fopen or are you opening the file into an object and updating the object?  I'm used to seeing a log file class (most of the time created in house) and the object is opened at the beginning of the application and reused throughout.  That way the log file is open while the application is open.  If you want to be able to read the file while the app is open, make sure to flush the buffer after each write.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity, I want to use the file throughout the application end.i use the fopen fn in each fn in mydll (which is imported by application),so wherever this dll fn call occurred ,that time file open held,at-last in fn end i close the file-pointer...

Comment: My dll having some function with fopen fn to get a argument lists of all my user-defined dll..that dll and my log file is available throughout the application ,now in main process ,process using logfile ,that time the second process cannot access the same file ...Is there any way to proceed with file -process synchronization ..in native code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using a different file for each process that uses your DLL then the problem is that you have the potential for multiple processes trying to access the same resource.

You should do one of the following:

1. Change your code so that it uses a
   separate file for each calling
   process.
2. Change it so that it uses
   semaphores, mutexes or critcial
   sections and wait states to control 
   access to the file.
3. Or rewrite your  DLL so that it runs
   as a process in  its own right and
   directly controls  data passed to it
   to place into the  file.

Comment: Quote: "how can manage a file ,which is used only from one process at a time"

Comment: @ChrisBD ,I think 2 nd point is suitable for me ,if semaphores,mutexes are possible via c,c++ ,give some references ,its appreciated ,another two points will give me some difficulty ..i feel so .thanks for ur valuable info...

Comment: Here's the MSDN page on mutexes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684266%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Rajakumar - I think that mutexs are the best route here as they work across processes as well as threads. 
Thanks for the link Eric.